# Add a matrix to a sub matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

`y` is 40x4x10, `y(i,:,:)` is 1x4x10, and `K` is 4x10.

I would like to: `y(i,:,:) = y(i,:,:) + K` but I get a dimension error. I cannot use squeeze because I need the rest of `y`.

How do I perform this addition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [permute](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) the dimensions, to make `K` 1x4x10, like this:

```
y(i,:,:) = y(i,:,:) + permute(K, [3 1 2])
```

Note `K` is "kind of" 4x10x1. We are asking to consider first the 3rd dimension, then the 1st, and the 2nd.

Comment: I guess I can assume all "hidden" singleton dimensions are at the end?
e.g. `K` is also 4x10x1x1.